# is the a module similar to data_export_import that includes user roles?

Tags: 7, users, importing-exporting

I am using the [Data Export Import](https://drupal.org/project/data_export_import) module to migrate data from my live site to my dev site.  It works fine in all cases except user roles.  For some reason, many (but sometimes not all) users lose the user roles that are assigned to them.  Is there a more advanced module that can handle an export-import of nodes and user (preserving node references and NIDs) which also migrates user roles?

If not, I am considering writing some rules to save and reset the roles as stated here:

[Programmatically assign user role](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/49533/programmatically-assign-user-role?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I have never used [**Data Export Import**](https://drupal.org/project/data_export_import), so I don't know whether it has special features or functions that you need for your use case.

For the use case of exporting *everything* (except file and media attachements) from my live site to my dev site, I use [**Backup and Migrate**](https://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate).

What it does is not in any way "advanced". It just mirrors the entire database, including content (nodes etc.), users and taxonomy terms. All references including NIDs are preserved, and user roles are also preserved.

There is nothing in your question that suggests that **Backup and Migrate** may not serve your use-case, but I may have overlooked something.

Comment: My goal is to only copy user created content, including user accounts (not including site configuration settings like views and rules.)  Features did not work out, so I chose to use data export import.  Is Backup and Migrate able to transfer only user generated content?

Comment: @Hoytman: "Is Backup and Migrate able to transfer only user generated content?" Not really. You *can* create "profiles" to migrate only specific tables, but you need to know a *lot* about Drupal internals to create a profile that exports only the stuff you want to export and not miss anything important.  I don't use it like that. I use it to *mirror* my entire live site on dev when I want to debug a specific issue (debugging on a live site is not considered a good idea).